# Saving video after tapping use in UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c

I am have an app that calls `UIImagePickerController`, and you take video using the controller. After you take the video, I want the video to be saved into the camera roll after clicking use in the `UIImagePickerController`.

Can you help me?

Oh, and `UIImagePickerController` comes with the option to switch to video, default photo. I want this to be only video, not photo.

My current code is :

```
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
picker.mediaTypes=[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
```

Answer (score 8):

Once you have implemented the following delegate method, pressing the 'Use' button will save your recorded video to the camera roll.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSURL *recordedVideoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedVideoURL
                               completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}
        ];
    } 
    [library release];

}
```

---

Use the following to set the capture mode to video :

```
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```

Here is the complete code that I use to launch the image picker for video recording :

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
    imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to save the video using the absoluteURL of the URL but it didn't work

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];    
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaURL.absoluteString, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

It finally worked using the path property:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([mediaURL path], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

From the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` class reference:

> To save a still image to the user’s Camera Roll album, call the
>   `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function from within the body of the
>   `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method. To save a
>   movie to the user’s Camera Roll album, instead call the
>   `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` function. These functions,
>   described in UIKit Function Reference, save the image or movie only;
>   they do not save metadata.

Your UIImagePickerControllerDelegate may look something like this...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:@"mediaType"];

    if (![mediaType isEqualToString:kUTTypeMovie])
        return;

    NSURL *mediaURL = [info objectForKey:@"mediaURL"];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaURL.absoluteString, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
}

- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *)contextInfo
{
    if (!videoPath && error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving video to saved photos roll: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        // Handle error;
        return;
    }

    // Video was saved properly. UI may need to be updated here.
}
```

Notice that I've implemented the completion selector for `UISaveVideoToSavedPhotosAlbum()`. If it were to fail for any reason, the error would be reported here and you can then handle it appropriately.